# How to correctly control the $dirty and $pristine state of an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create an angular directive that will compose a KendoUI TreeView control and a text input so that it searches for the entered text and selects the item. I have this functionality working however I would like the directive to behave well in a form so that when a check box value is changed the form's dirty property is set.

Unfortunately the behaviour just now is that when somebody enters text in the input the from gets set to dirty (not desired behaviour) and checking a check-box has no effect.

I was hoping to call $setDirty() on the form but its not visible to the functions I have, and I was hoping there was a clean way of making it visible rather than adding it to $scope, this also won't resolve the problem of $dirty being set to true but entering search text either.

I've created a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/9EpSDQ) to demonstrate the problem.

Here's the code for the directive:

```js
var serviceRoot = "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service";
 angular.module("KendoDemos", ["kendo.directives"])
   .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
       data: [{
         text: "Cat"
       }, {
         text: "Dog",
         items: [{
           text: "Fido"
         }, {
           text: "Rover"
         }]
       }, {
         text: "Rabbit",
         checked: true
       }]
     });
   });

 (function() {
   'use strict';


   var app = angular.module('KendoDemos');

   var template = '<div> <div class="input-group">  <input type="text" ng-click="textNotFound=false"      class="form-control" placeholder="Find node"      ng-model="searchText" ng-enter="search()" ng-esc="searchText=\'\';textNotFound = false;">  <div class="input-group-btn">   <span class="btn btn-default" ng-click="search()"><span class="fa fa-search clickable"    style="font-size: 14px; height: 18px"></span></span>  </div> </div> <div id="treeview" kendo-tree-view="searchTree" k-data-source="dataSource" k-load-on-demand="false" k-on-check="onCheck(kendoEvent)"       k-options="{checkboxes:true }">  <span k-template>{{dataItem.text}}</span> </div></div>'

   app.directive('searchableTree', function() {
     //Usage:
     //<div data-searchable-tree ng-model="vm.treeData"></div>
     var directive = {
       template: template,
       require: '?^form',
       replace: true,
       transclude: true,
       scope: {
         'dataSource': '=ngModel',
         'controlId': '@id'
       },
       restrict: 'AE',
       link: function($scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
         $scope.search = function(id) {
           var tree = $scope.searchTree;
           var node = tree.findByText($scope.searchText);
           tree.expandTo($scope.searchTree.dataItem(node));
           tree.select(node);
           tree.dataItem(node).set("checked", true);
           //var checkbox = $(node).find(":checkbox");
           //checkbox.prop("checked", true);
         }
         $scope.setSelected = function(id) {
           alert(id);
         }
         $scope.onSelect = function(id) {
           alert(id);
         }
         $scope.onCheck = function(e) {
           var checkbox = $(e.node).find(":checkbox");
           var checked = checkbox.prop("checked");
           //updateValidity(e.node, checked);
         }
       }
     };
     return directive;
   });

   app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
     return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
         if (event.which === 13) {
           scope.$apply(function() {
             scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
           });

           event.preventDefault();
         }
       });
     };
   });

   app.directive('ngEsc', function() {
     return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
         if (event.which === 27) {
           scope.$apply(function() {
             scope.$eval(attrs.ngEsc);
           });

           event.preventDefault();
         }
       });
     };
   });

 })();
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

html {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#example {
  text-align: center;
}
.demo-section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 320px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 2em;
}
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name='myForm'>
      <div name='myTree' data-searchable-tree ng-model="treeData"></div>
    </form>
    <hr/>

    <div>Directive is {{myForm.myTree.$dirty ? 'dirty' : 'pristine'}}</div>
    <hr/>
    <div>Form is {{myForm.$dirty ? 'dirty' : 'pristine'}}</div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

2/8/2016 addendum:  since writing this I've realized that the scope method is only available in debug mode.  I don't recommend this for production code.

I had a similar problem and actually came up with a pretty simple solution to solve it.  If you have a reference to an element, there is a `scope()` method you can use to find the scope it exists in.  Given that, this solution will work:

```
  function dirtyParent(uid)
    {
      var formEl = angular.element(angular.element('#' + uid).closest('form'));

      var formScope = formEl.scope();

      var formName = formEl.attr('name');

      formScope[formName].$setDirty();
    }
```

This function goes and gets the element from the DOM, finds its most recent ancestor that is a form, grabs the name and scope for that element, and then finds the form controller on the scope (which shares its name with the `name` attribute of the form) and calls the `$setDirty()` method on it.  In this way, your controller will be set to the $dirty state.

It seems like you might be able to skip the DOM traversal with the $formController information in New Dev's answer, but I didn't realize that when I wrote this code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here, so without going into specifics of your particular directive, you should understand the following:

**ng-model:**

You should `require: "ngModel"` rather than use it as a scope variable. `ng-model` is a directive through which you properly integrate with other forms and validators. `ng-model` is DOM-agnostic on purpose, and should be used as a conceptual conduit between model and view values.

If you do this properly, you won't need to `require: "form"`.

**You have a custom input control:**

Recognize that you are effectively building a custom input directive. It sets the model a certain way, and it renders UI a certain way.

Look at [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example) from Angular docs on creating a custom input directive.

**Using ng-model in a template of a custom directive:**

Now, the problem with `$dirty` that you are seeing is because the `ng-model` inside your directive (`ng-model="searchText"`) integrates with the outside form completely unaware of the fact it is part of another custom input control.

`ngModel` directive searches (see [src](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L320)) for a form directive up the DOM hierarchy and ends up finding the form within which your directive resides.

One way to deal with this is not to use `ng-model` inside your template, and do `element.on('input')` (or something) to detect change, and set the view value of your "required" `ngModel` appropriately.

The other is too "trick" the `ngModel` into believing that the form controller is null, so it would not update it.

This is quite easy to do - but I can't comment on whether this is future-proof. In the `pre-link` of your directive do the following:

```
link: {
  pre: function(scope, element){
     // this will trip the search, and apply a `nullFormCtrl` internally, 
     // which doesn't do anything.
     element.data("$formController", null); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I attempted to require the ngModel instead of creating a scope variable but no luck initially, it just breaks my binding to the TreeView control. I had already looking at the Angular documentation but quite honestly their example is so contrived it doesn't really shed much light on the subject

Comment: @Mark, You should still use `ng-model` on the TreeView directive. It has nothing to do with `require`

Comment: Here's the updated link: http://plnkr.co/lkGQFi It still doesn't update the directive. If I remove dateSource from scope and change the references from dataSource to ngModel it doesn't work at all

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't update the directive"? it doesn't update the form's dirty/pristine status, but it didn't before either - is this what you wanted?

Comment: If I check or uncheck a checkbox the form's $dirty property is still unafected